# Setting the PATH for all Jupyter Notebooks for a user

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to set my JupyterLab notebooks (running on an Ubuntu server with a bash shell) so that `$HOME/.local/bin` is in the `PATH` environment variable.

I have tried adding this path to the `PATH` variable in my `.bashrc`, and I source my `.bashrc` from my `.bash_profile` file, and, because I wanted to try everything, I also tried adding this variable in my `.profile`.

Within a normal, login shell, the path is set correctly.

```bash
echo $PATH
# /home/USER/.local/bin:/home/USER/.local/bin:/opt/conda/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Where `USER` is actually my username. Notice that `/home/USER/.local/bin` is on the path twice because I put it in both `.bashrc` and `.profile`.

Within a Jupyter notebook:

```py
import os
os.environ["PATH"]
# /bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/jupyterhub/bin
```

In my `.bashrc` and within my `.profile` I have

```bash
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

And in my `.bash_profile`

```bash
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Is there some Jupyter-specific variable that I need to set so that I can change my path? I have tried restarting the JupyterHub service. Is there some cache where this variables are stored that I need to clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using `JupyterHub` as a service and I assume you followed instruction from [install doc](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/installation-guide-hard.html)

Documentation from config file says(from file `jupyterhub_config.py`)

```py
#  Environment variables that end up in the single-user server's process come from 3 sources:
#    - This `environment` configurable
#    - The JupyterHub process' environment variables that are listed in `env_keep`
#    - Variables to establish contact between the single-user notebook and the hub (such as JUPYTERHUB_API_TOKEN)
```

As this options should mostly be used to add environment variables for all users, but to create per user `PATH` you can create startup script, for example create
`/opt/jupyterhub/bin/start.sh` with content

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
exec jupyterhub-singleuser "$@"
```

Make it executable `chmod +x /opt/jupyterhub/bin/start.sh`

Next you need to modify your config `/opt/jupyterhub/etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py`, open it and find line `c.Spawner.cmd`, by default it's commented, so changed it to

```py
c.Spawner.cmd = ['/opt/jupyterhub/bin/start.sh']
```

It will execute script when you login(in Jupyter) and set `PATH` to the expected value

And the final step it to restart your `Jupyterhub service` using:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart jupyterhub
```

---

If you want more advanced configuration you can create for each user `$HOME/jupyter_startup.sh` and then `start.sh` add something like(before `exec`)

```bash
if [ -f "$HOME/jupyter_startup.sh" ] ; then
    source "$HOME/jupyter_startup.sh"
fi
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I wonder if it is possible to use the 'environment' configurable to add to the PATH environment variable. Probably not, which is why you showed how to do it with c.Spawner.cmd.

Comment: The issue is that `PATH` is not simple as other env variables, because we need to keep what was and just extend it, using `environment` normally looks like `c.Spawner.environment = {
  "FOO": "BAR"
}` but limit is config file is executed in context of JupyterHub on startup(so `root` in my case), so we don't know target user, it makes everything more difficult and I don't see the way to get it working. You can create own `Sprawner` like [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/spawned-user-process-not-visible-from-other-machine/21029/4) but it's also not simple